# Running a progress bar using Background Controller in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar, backgroundworker, threadpool

I don't have a thorough knowledge about controlling threads in c#. I want to create a progress bar while running a method.

I have two forms:

1. `Form1` is the form which show up as you run the app. It has a button called `btnScrape`. When it is clicked the method should be called, the form with the progress bar should show up. `Form1` should be disabled to the user until the progress bar is completed.
2. `ProgressBarForm` - this has the progress bar and a label.

The code is as follows.

```
   //In Form1.cs I have a button.
      private void btnScrape_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //gather data for folloeing parameters from the form.
             Controller cntrlr = new Controller(urlFilePath, destinationPath, destinationfilename,cmbDepth.SelectedIndex);

            cntrlr.Vmain(); // this is the method in controller class. while this is running i want show the progress bar.
    }

   // in Contrller class     
    class Controller{
          List<string> urlList = null; 
          URLFileReader urlFileReader = null;
          HTTPWorker httpWorker = null;
          SourceReader srcreader = null;
          ReportWriter reportWriter = null;

           string urlFilePath, destinationPath, destinationFileName;
           int depth;

    public Controller(string urlFilePath,string destinationPath,string destinationFileName,int depth)
    {
        this.urlFilePath = urlFilePath;
        this.destinationPath = destinationPath;
        this.destinationFileName = destinationFileName;
        this.urlList = new List<string>();
        this.urlFileReader = new URLFileReader();
        this.httpWorker = new HTTPWorker(this.destinationPath);
        this.reportWriter = new ReportWriter(this.destinationPath,this.destinationFileName);
        this.srcreader = new SourceReader(this.reportWriter);
        this.depth = depth;

    }

       //this is the method
         public void Vmain(){

              this.urlFileReader.ReadURL(urlFilePath);
              this.urlList = urlFileReader.geturlList();           

              string pageSrc;

                foreach (string requestUrl in urlList)
                {
                   //do sruff for requestUrl
                   //the progressbar should move as the urlList iterate.
                   //additionally i want the label on the top of progress bar to     display the current "requestUrl"
                   //as the urlList is over i want quit from the progressbar window and come back to Form1. Till the progrss bar is completed Form1 should be disabled for the user.

                }

         }



    }
```

Please explain what is happening there and give a working code if you can. Thank you in advance. There were not any perfect answer that worked for me, even though I spent two days for this. I tried with `BackgroundWorker`and  threads. But no solution found. :(

Answer (score 1):

In the main form you could use this code:

```
    private Progressfrm _loadForm;
    private void ShowProgress()
    {
        ToggleForm();
        _loadForm = new Progressfrm();
        _loadForm.ShowDialog();
        var tcheck = new Thread(CheckLoadedProgress);
        tcheck.Start();
        //do stuff here
    }
    private void CheckLoadedProgress()
    {
        while (_loadForm.IsAccessible) { }
        ToggleForm();
    }
    private void ToggleForm()
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() => Enabled = !Enabled));
    }
    private void btnScrape_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tform = new Thread(ShowProgress);
        tform.Start();
    }
```

Then the Progress-`Form` will appear until it is filled:

```
    private ProgressBar _progressBar;
    private void Progressfrm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _progressBar = new ProgressBar { Size = new Size(100, 20), Location = new Point(10, 10) };
        Controls.Add(_progressBar);
        _progressBar.Show();
        Refresh();
        LoadProgress();
    }
    private void LoadProgress()
    {
        while (_progressBar.Value < 100)
        {
            _progressBar.Value++;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Close();
    }
```

On this Form you have to add the Event `Shown` and add the code like in my example. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sure this will work. But what i want is something different. I want to increase the progress bar while that foreach is running in the Vmain method. Can u please tell me the exact solution. It'll be a great help to understand what is going on.

Comment: I edited my answer. I modified only the mainform, may this helps now.

Comment: Sorry that, I am getting back four years later. But this really helped me that time.

Answer (score 0):

Use BackgroundWorker class to output progressBar and statusLabel changes:

```
BackgroundWorker bgw;
private void btnScrape_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
  bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
  bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
  bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgw_ProgressChanged);
  bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    bgw.ReportProgress(i);
  }
}

private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

This is only an example how to update controls in an asynchron way.

Comment: Thank you. Can u apply this to my problem. to which form should i  add a background worker? I can't identify the correct workflow when using background worker. Thanx again for the help.